# Sharepoint Custom Webservices

Tags: wss-3.0

I am working with WSS 3.0 on a Windows 2003 R2 Server.

I have been tasked with adapting an old Sharepoint plugin to work with our new software, unfortunately for me there are no developers here who worked on it and no documentation to be found.

This project uses a custom Sharepoint webservice, methods such as `DoesAccountHaveFullAccess()`, `GetListItems()` and `ConnectionTest()`. I believe they are meant as wrappers.

I am having trouble working out how this used to work with WSS 3.0 and where it should be hosted (on the Sharepoint site? Sharepoint admin? Different site?), several [websites](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html) have indicated to me that custom web services where not supported until Sharepoint 2007 which adds to my confusion.

Could someone confirm whether WSS3 supports webservices in the manner?

Comment: WSS 3.0 is SharePoint 2007 (it's just the "small" version")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating web services is certainly available in WSS 3.0 as can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040%28v=office.12%29.aspx) so you should be able to get a lot of info there. Not much else to go on so hopefully this will get you enough to form a better idea of what you need to do.